# How to convert Bitmap to VideoFrame？

Tags: java, android, webrtc

I want to know how to convert Bitmap to VideoFrame

I am connecting the TFlite model to Android webrtc for video processing, and I need to convert Bitmap and VideoFrame to each other. So I want to know how to convert Bitmap to VideoFrame

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.